# Cordova navigator.notification.alert() doesn't work (android)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am using cordova 5.0.0. I have added the notifications plugin, but 
 navigator.notification.alert(.) still doesn't work. I add a plain alert() in front of the  navigator.notification.alert(), the regular alert works, but this doesn't.

I saw there were some posts about this issue on stackoverflow, unfortunately, the solutions cannot help at my side. Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: do you get any error on logcat?

Comment: I haven't used logcat yet. It works today...... I did nothing, just turn my laptop off and re-open it today.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that you have the plugin installed correctly in your generated config.xml. You should see something like this:

```
<feature name="Notification">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification" />
</feature>
```

Make sure you're calling the plugin like this:

```
function alertDismissed() {
    // do something
}

navigator.notification.alert(
    'You are the winner!',    // message
    'alertDismissed',         // callback
    'Game Over',              // title
    'Done'                    // buttonName
);
```

Comment: Yes, I do have this plugin for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I added `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` in index.html (before all others script tags) and it's works now.

Answer (score 0):

Please check it's availability before use this plugin.

```
if(navigator.notification == undefined)
{
        alert(msg);
        return false;
}
else
{
navigator.notification.alert(message, 
                             callback, 
                             title,
                             buttonName);
}
```